# Openlayers/GeoServer WFS caching, tiles or any optimization

Tags: openlayers, geoserver, epsg

I'm developping a Web application using OpenLayers 3.20.0 with layers coming from GeoServer, linked to an Oracle data source.
This application is using mostly ImageWMS layer, and also a Vector layer for interaction and edition.
The issue is that the map is very slow with more than 30000 polylines drawn, and I would like to make the process faster :-)

So I would like to know what is the best way to do. I found two ways :

- change my Vector layer in ImageWMS layer, and load manually needed features only on selection or edition, but it asks me a certain amount of modifications in my code
- use VectorTile layer instead of Vector layer, I guess it should work like ImageWMS and a tile system so that data are loaded only according to the view of the map (Am i good ?)

I looked for samples of VectorTile, but they are not very numerous (most of the time it's about OpenLayers 2), and the documentation is a little poor.

The big unknown about the layer declaration is about the VectorTile source. An URL must be defined, and I found in documentation that I have to put {x}/{y}/{z} parameters, but where exactly, and how is built this URL ? (see https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_VectorTile-VectorTile.html, the 'url' option)

As sample, my current Vector source has an URL like this : /geoserver/ANF/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=ANF:myLayer&outputFormat=application%2Fjson

So to define VectorTile source, how do I define my URL, and what do have I to do on GeoServer side to configure my layer in the correct way ?
I found this resource : https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/vectortiles/tutorial.html

The only vector tile format I have that is not image type on GeoServer is 'application/json;type=utfgrid'. And when I put '@pbf/{z}/{x}/{-y}.pbf' at the end of my URL like the sample, I got errors, but I guess it's not the right way.

Any help would be greatly appreciated to give me more precision on how to make work a VectorTile layer and source with GeoServer, or another way to optimize the map I create.

Many thanks.

## EDIT

After some answers, I'm coming to this sample of code :

```
this._view = new ol.View({
    center: [74000, 96000],
    projection: 'EPSG:2169',
    zoom: 13,
    maxZoom: 24,
    minZoom: 11
});

this._map = new ol.Map(
    {
        view: this._view,
        controls: [
            new ol.control.Zoom(),
            new ol.control.ScaleLine()
        ]                
    });

let vectorSourceURL: string = `/geoserver/ANF/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=ANF:myLayer&outputFormat=application%2Fjson`;

let source = new ol.source.VectorTile({
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON({
        defaultDataProjection: 'EPSG:2169',
        geometryName: 'GEOLOC'
    }),
    tileUrlFunction: function (tileCoord, pixelRatio, projection) {
        return vectorSourceURL + '&bbox=' + source.getTileGrid().getTileCoordExtent(tileCoord).join(',') + ',EPSG:2169';
    },
    tileGrid: ol.tilegrid.createXYZ(),
    projection: 'EPSG:2169'
});

let layer = new ol.layer.VectorTile({
    source: source,
    renderOrder: null
});

layer.set('name', 'myLayer');
layer.set('title', 'myLayer');
```

This code falls to the following error :

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'getUnits' of null
>       at ol.renderer.canvas.VectorTileLayer.createReplayGroup_ (ol-debug.js:29814)
>       at ol.renderer.canvas.VectorTileLayer.drawTileImage (ol-debug.js:29886)
>       at ol.renderer.canvas.VectorTileLayer.ol.renderer.canvas.TileLayer.prepareFrame
>   (ol-debug.js:26557)
>       at ol.renderer.canvas.Map.renderFrame (ol-debug.js:30302)
>       at ol.Map.renderFrame_ (ol-debug.js:42107)
>       at ol.Map. (ol-debug.js:41013)
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (zone.js:421)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:3815)
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (zone.js:420)
>       at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)

It appears that the issue comes now from EPSG:2169. An sample with EPSG:3857 works well (see answers).

Am I missing something ?

Many thanks !

Comment: Vector tiles (or simply a vector layer with a tile grid loading strategy) might be more efficient in requests to the server, but slow rendering when there are many features loaded is often caused by inefficient styling, such as a style function generating a new style for each feature.

Answer (score 1):

Vector tiles don't need to be .pbf or use XYZ urls.  Here's the OpenLayers WFS example reworked to use the WFS url as the source for vector tiles.  When zoomed out to cover the whole of Canada it does seem more responsive than the original example.

```js
  var vectorSource = new ol.source.VectorTile({
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
    tileUrlFunction: function(tileCoord, pixelRatio, projection) {
      return 'https://ahocevar.com/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&' +
          'version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=osm:water_areas&' +
          'outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:3857&' +
          'bbox=' + vectorSource.getTileGrid().getTileCoordExtent(tileCoord).join(',') + ',EPSG:3857';
    },
    tileGrid: ol.tilegrid.createXYZ()
  });

  var vector = new ol.layer.VectorTile({
    source: vectorSource,
    style: new ol.style.Style({
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1.0)',
        width: 2
      })
    })
  });

  var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM()
  });

  var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [raster, vector],
    target: document.getElementById('map'),
    view: new ol.View({
      center: [-8908887.277395891, 5381918.072437216],
      maxZoom: 19,
      zoom: 12
    })
  });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/3.20.0/ol.css" type="text/css">
<!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/3.20.0/ol.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

There does seem to be a problem using that code with projections based on proj4 but it should work using a tile load function

```
let viewProjection = ol.proj.get('EPSG:2169');

let format = new ol.format.GeoJSON({
        defaultDataProjection: viewProjection,
        featureProjection: viewProjection,
        geometryName: 'GEOLOC'
    });

let source = new ol.source.VectorTile({
    tileUrlFunction: function (tileCoord, pixelRatio, projection) {
        return vectorSourceURL + '&bbox=' + source.getTileGrid().getTileCoordExtent(tileCoord).join(',') + ',EPSG:2169';
    },
    tileLoadFunction: function (tile, url) {
        tile.setProjection(viewProjection);
        tile.setLoader(function() {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.onload = function() {
                tile.setFeatures(format.readFeatures(xhr.responseText));
            }
            xhr.open("GET", url, true);
            xhr.send();
        });
    },
    tileGrid: ol.tilegrid.createXYZ(),
    projection: viewProjection
});
```

Comment: Thank you Mike, unfortunately I get this error when I try it in my code : 
Cannot read property 'getUnits' of null
    at ol.renderer.canvas.VectorTileLayer.createReplayGroup_ (ol-debug.js:29814)
    at ol.renderer.canvas.VectorTileLayer.drawTileImage (ol-debug.js:29886)...

Do you have any idea of what it means ?

Comment: I found this thread that is exactly my issue : https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/6946
Linked to another issue, but I don't see what I have to do. Upgrade my OpenLayers version ?

Comment: getUnits will be related to the projection. Presumably you are using something other than EPSG:3857 for either your view or data?

Comment: Indeed, I use EPSG:2169 that is for Luxembourg. Is it a limitation ? Because I have to use this projection.

Comment: `ol.source.VectorTile` must use the same projection as the view and it must be set as an option in the source if it's not EPSG:3857.  To keep things simple the WFS should accept bbox and return data in the same projection, otherwise the vector tile source will need a custom loader.

Comment: I updated my question with code sample. As you see, I define EPSG:2169 everywhere it's possible. So everything should work in the same projection, right ? Am I missing something in client code or maybe it's a configuration issue on GeoServer side ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to speed up your application is to switch to using a WMTS (or tiled WMS) layer. This way your application can make use of the browser cache to only request tiles it hasn't seen before and the server need only render them once as they are cached to disk there too.

You almost certainly don't need all 300K features for your editing so trying to filter the WFS to just the bounding box of the requested area will help.

Finally, the biggest win would probably come from switching to a proper spatial database like PostGIS.

Comment: Thank you Ian, unfortunately I can't use PostGIS, I have to use Oracle, it's a prerequisite of our client. The current ImageWMS layers I have are fast enough for now, the issue really comes from the Vector layer, that's why I guess that a VectorTile layer will do the trick.